# Dynamic SQL - Use declared VARCHAR in SET SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to use the declared variable **@CodeID** inside the SQL string?  When I run following statement I get the "Invalid object name (..)" error.

```
WHILE @FolderID <= @FolderMaxID
BEGIN
    SELECT @Db  = Db 
    FROM #Folders 
    WHERE ID =  @FolderID

    SET @Sql = N'

        DECLARE @CodeID NVARCHAR(256)

        SELECT TOP(1)  @CodeID=CodeType
        FROM ' + @Db + '.bla.Field 
        WHERE Name= ''Example''

        SELECT DISTINCT C.Name
        FROM ' + @Db + '.Document 
            INNER JOIN ' + @Db + '.bla.Code_@CodeID  C  ON D.ID = C.ID'
        
    EXEC ( @Sql )
    SET @FolderID = @FolderID + 1
END
```

Comment: This is why it's advised to *not* use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: Also don't blindly inject your object names, delimit identify them properly with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Finally, why are you spamming the `NOLOCK` hint all over your queries here? Why are you using such a hint? `NOLOCK` isn't a "magic go faster button", it's a don't care about wrong data button. I suggest having a read of [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: There's no reason for such code at all. Neither the `@Db` parameter nor the `NOLOCK` hint which *doesn't* improve performance. It returns dirty and duplicate data instead, with a chance of throwing errors. If your query is slow, `NOLOCK` won't make it faster

Comment: `WHILE @FolderID <= @FolderMaxID` Just use a cursor. Looping over an identity column you created in your temp table is just a more error-prone version. And `@Db` is either mis-named or mis-used. A three party name includes a database name as the first element. A two-part name includes a schema name as the first element.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) and also, more generally, a wealth of information here: https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? There's a better solution probably. Why the loop and dynamic SQL? That `@Db` can't be a database anyway, it can only be a schema. `Code_@CodeID` can't be a table name either. Maybe if it's quoted, but I've never tried somethin like this

Comment: Thank you for all the advice. How do I use @CodeID?

Comment: You don't. What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Can you elaborate why I shouldn't use it and how to fix my statement accordingly?

Comment: @jonas as mentioned, you are likely far better off explaining what you are *actually* trying to achieve here. Why do you need a dynamic schema reference in the first place? Why do you have multiple tables with the same definition (presumably) on different schemas? Why is the data not all in one table, with a column used to denote the information you are using the schema to represent? The fact you want to do an operation against all these tables suggests that they are related. What do you want to *do* with `@CodeID`? You assign its value and then do nothing with it, making it pointless anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you need two levels of dynamic SQL, with the first level inserting the database name (from #folders), and the second level inserting a constructed table name (based on the CodeType column of the database-local bla.Field table).

I do not know of any way to parameterize database names or table names using sp_executesql, so I'm sticking with build-up dynamic SQL and EXEC ().  (If someone makes a case for preferring sp_executesql over EXEC when not useing parameters, then it may be worth the switch.)

Try something like:

```
WHILE @FolderID <= @FolderMaxID
BEGIN
    SELECT @Db  = Db 
    FROM #Folders 
    WHERE ID =  @FolderID

    SET @Sql = N'

        DECLARE @CodeID NVARCHAR(256)

        SELECT TOP(1)  @CodeID=CodeType
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.Field 
        WHERE Name= ''Example''

        DECLARE @Sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
            SELECT DISTINCT C.Name
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.Document D
                INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.'' + QUOTENAME(''Code_'' + @CodeID) + '' C  ON D.ID = C.ID
        ''
        EXEC @sql2
        '
    
    EXEC ( @Sql )
    SET @FolderID = @FolderID + 1
END
```

This implements dynamic SQL within dynamic SQL. Doubled quotes in the outer sql template become single quotes in the inner sql. The original posted code seemed to be missing a schema qualifier and alias for the Document table, so I inserted them ("bla" and "D"). I also added QUOTENAME around the injected names as suggested by Larnu.

The first level of dynamic sql would generate something like:

```
SELECT TOP(1)  @CodeID=CodeType
FROM [db1].bla.Field 
WHERE Name= 'Example'

DECLARE @Sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT DISTINCT C.Name
    FROM [db1].bla.Document D
        INNER JOIN [db1].bla.' + QUOTENAME('Code_' + @CodeID) + ' C  ON D.ID = C.ID
'
EXEC @sql2
```

The second level would generate something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Name
FROM [db1].bla.Document D
    INNER JOIN [db1].bla.[Code_Table1] C  ON D.ID = C.ID
```

Note that each loop iteration will generate a separate result. If you wish to combine results, you will need to define a #temp table, insert the individual results into that table, and then select the combined results at the end of your script.

Note that I haven't tested the specific code above, so it might need some debugging (add "PRINT @sql2" before the EXEC) if it doesn't work straight out.

ADDENDUM

Per @trenton-ftw comments below, an out parameter can be used to capture the result of the first query so that it may be included in the second query without the need for nesting. Two executions are still required. Below is a revised example.

```
DECLARE @Folders TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Db sysname)
INSERT @Folders VALUES ('db1'), ('db2')

DECLARE @SearchName NVARCHAR(256) = 'Example' 
DECLARE @Db sysname
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CodeID NVARCHAR(256)

DECLARE @FolderMaxID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Folders)
DECLARE @FolderID INT = 1
WHILE @FolderID <= @FolderMaxID
BEGIN
    SELECT @Db = Db 
    FROM @Folders 
    WHERE ID = @FolderID

    SET @Sql = N'
        SET @CodeID = @SearchName + ''-Test''
        --SELECT TOP(1) @CodeID = CodeType
        --FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.Field 
        --WHERE Name = @SearchName'
    PRINT @Sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,
        N'@SearchName NVARCHAR(256), @CodeID NVARCHAR(256) OUTPUT',
        @SearchName, @CodeID OUTPUT

    SET @Sql = N'
        --SELECT DISTINCT C.Name
        --FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.Document D
        --    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + '.bla.' + QUOTENAME('Code_' + @CodeID) + ' C  ON D.ID = C.ID'
    PRINT @Sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    SET @FolderID = @FolderID + 1
END
```

For demo purposes, I also parameterized the search name as an input parameter and added some temporary code to make it stand-alone testable.  A final version would uncomment the actual sql, and remove the print statements and the test @CodeID assignemnt.

Comment: Follow-up. If you intend to parameterize  the 'Example' value, we would then have a case for using sp_executesql, at least for the outer case.

Comment: Beyond the other issues with actually using this code, `If someone makes a case for preferring sp_executesql over EXEC when not useing parameters, then it may be worth the switch`. How about instead of having to nest dynamic SQL to retrieve the value of @CodeID variable for a second query, you just use `OUTPUT` parameters in `sys.sp_executesql` to retrieve the value from your first query and you can then un-nest your dynamic SQL and just run the next statement inline with the rest of your code. Way easier than nesting dynamic SQL.

Comment: @trenton-ftw - Excellent observation. I've posted an addendum above. Feel free to suggest other improvements.